# Unable to format my Date into the right format?

Tags: java

My date is of the format: mon/jan/13/20/01/56/0000/2014

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "mon/jan/13/20/01/56/0000/2014"

```
//fix the date and time
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE/MMM/dd/kk/mm/ss/zzzz/yyyy");
Date d = sdf.parse(tweet[0].replaceAll(" ","/"));   
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss").format(d));
```

I want it to be in this format: `MM/DD/YY KK:MM:SS`

I have browsed lots of SO posts but unable to find anything useful.

Infact, the piece of code that I have obtained aforementioned is from a SO post.

However, I am getting the error.

Comment: ParseException as my post says.

Comment: What's your default `Locale`?

Comment: I don't know, what should it be ?

Comment: Do the following `Locale.getDefault()`. What does it return?

Comment: The tweet is the "mon/jan/13/20/01/56/0000/2014"

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Returns nothing.

Comment: ...Do `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());`

Comment: I obviously did that too, returns nothing. Tried Locale.ENGLISH, same.

Comment: "Returns nothing." Are you just being careless? ;)

Comment: Guys, I think I should add more. My string comes in the form of:mon/jan/13/20/01/56/0000/2014 I want it like this MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss.

Comment: What is the `0000` meant to be? The timezone? In that case, it is badly formatted and must be changed to fit the requirements of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: There must be a way out. This is how I got the data files and I think there was a +0000 before there, but it's removed. I am sure there is a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TimeZone is in incorrect format, see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone). Try with `mon/jan/13/20/01/56/+0000/2014`.

Edit:
I supposed you can fix it with the hint above; anyway - not very clean code, but should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE/MMM/dd/kk/mm/ss/zzzz/yyyy");
String date = tweet[0].replaceAll(" ","/");
if (date.split("/")[6].length() == 4) {
    date = new StringBuilder(date).insert(20, "+").toString();
}
Date d = sdf.parse(date);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss").format(d));
```

Comment: Almost impossible... Could you provide message from the exception just to check if the string is corrected?

Comment: //fix the date and time
  String s = tweet[0].replaceAll(" ","/");
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("eee/mmm/dd/kk/mm/ss/zzzz/yyyy");
  
  Date d = sdf.parse(s); 
  System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy kk:mm:ss").format(d));

This is what I am doing and now I get a new error: Illegal pattern character 'e'

Comment: Use capital letters for EEE and MMM.

Comment: Artur fixed it for me. Thank you Artur.